# how to assign value to NodeLabelEditEventArgs variable

Tags: vb.net, treeview

i created this sub

```
  Sub CreateNewNode(tree As TreeView, e As NodeLabelEditEventArgs)
        Dim nodeTxt As String
        nodeTxt = e.Label

        If e.Node.Level = 0 Then
            Dim obj_carsType As New Cls_carsType
            Dim Entity As New tblcarsType
            Entity.Type = nodeTxt
            obj_carsType .Insert(Entity)

            Dim q = (From i In obj_logsType.Fill Select i.ID).Last

            e.CancelEdit = True
            tree.Nodes.Remove(e.Node)
            tree.Nodes.Add(nodeTxt & " : " & q.tostring)

  end sub

  Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseClick()
     e.Node.ContextMenuStrip =ContextMenuStrip1
  end sub

  Private Sub NEWITEmToolStripMenuItem_Click()

  end sub
```

in last sub need to call first sub. also in last sub if user click on NEWITEM i must call the first sub how can i do it?? please help me

Comment: Your question is not very clear...at nd = TreeView1.Nodes(1) you are referencing an existing node and overwriting the nd variable. Are you looking for TreeView.Nodes.Add(nd)?

Comment: Post more code, your question isn't clear

Comment: ok now i edit my code please help me...

Comment: Please paste the code that shows how NewItemToolsStripMenuItem_Click is being called..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
Private Sub NEWITEmToolStripMenuItem_Click(byval sender as object, byval e as eventargs)

CreateNewNode(ctype(sender, TreeView), ctype(e,NodeLabelEditEventArgs))

end sub
```

Comment: it dont work and show to me this error ** Unable to cast object of type System.EventArgs' to type System.Windows.Forms.NodeLabelEditEventArgs **

Comment: Please paste the code that shows how NewItemToolsStripMenuItem_Click is being called

Comment: it is like this: `TreeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(sender, e)`. when user click on newItem the code that is in the create new item must run , how can i do that ??